# Why Node.js email transfer failed?

Tags: node.js

I coded for sending emails from one account to another account.I already enable lesser secure app for my gmail 'jisan.cse16@gmail.com'.These are my code.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'jisan.cse16@gmail.com',
        pass: '*******'
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'jisan.cse16@gmail.com',
    to: 'uddin1607084@stud.kuet.ac.bd',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error,info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log('Email sent: '+info.response);
    }
});
```

But when I run this in command prompt using

```
node filename.js
```

Then email send fail and this log are given,

```
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q11sm12376707pfl.97 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1523:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:550:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (C:\Users\J.U.Jisan\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q11sm12376707pfl.97 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the settings on your gmail account to allow relaying mail through it?  Instructions are here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en